# Cómo sumar 1 a un campo con ceros sin perder los ceros?

Tags: sql-server

Busco tener un número que se incremente de uno en uno  sumando 1, pero el campo se debe rellenar con ceros y el campo debe ser de 10 díditos.
He intentado de algunas formas, pero la suma siempre me da sin ceros.

Lo que he intentado;

```
select  left('0000000'+cast(0 as varchar(10)),10) + max(id)+ 1  from usuarios
```

Lo que debería obtener:
0000000019

Lo que obtengo:
19

Otra forma:

```
SELECT replicate('0',8) + MAX(id)+ 1 FROM usuarios
```

Lo que debería obtener:
0000000019

Lo que obtengo:
19

"Aunque este caso no serviría porque cuando se llegue al id 100 el campo tendría 11 dígitos"

Otro ejemplo:

```
select REPLICATE('0',(10-len(MAX(id))))+ MAX(id) + 1 from usuarios
```

Lo que debería obtener:
0000000019

Lo que obtengo:
19

Ojalá puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Yo pregunto.. y si haces totalmente al reves?? si primero sumas, y despues agregas todos los ceros que quieras a la izquierda??? (aunque esto no seria logico, porque estas tratando un campo numerico como cadena solo para solucionar un problema que no es de la base de datos, es de tu vista)

Comment: Ya lo intenté y nada, sigo teniendo 19. El camp0 id es varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escenario:

```
Create table dbo.usuarios (id varchar(10),id2 int)
go
Insert into dbo.usuarios (id, id2)
values
('1',1),
('2',2),
('11',11),
('12',12),
('101',101),
('102',102),
('1001',1001),
('1002',1002);
go
```

Pongo dos columnas para elegir en función del tipo que sea.

```
Select
      RIGHT((CONCAT( (power(10,8)),(cast(usu.id as int) + 1))),8) as varcharPower
    , RIGHT((CONCAT( (replicate('0',8)),(cast(usu.id as int) + 1))),8) as varcharReplicate
    , RIGHT((CONCAT('00000000',(cast(usu.id as int) + 1))),8) as varcharLiteral
    , RIGHT((CONCAT( (power(10,8)),(usu.id2 + 1))),8) as intPower
    , RIGHT((CONCAT( (replicate('0',8)),(usu.id2 + 1))),8) as intReplicate
    , RIGHT((CONCAT('00000000',(usu.id + 1))),8) as intLiteral

    from dbo.usuarios usu;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las 3 soluciones, pasan por realizar la suma del dato + 1 encerrando esta entre paréntesis, de manera que si la columna es de tipo int o similar, sea `(col + 1)`.
Cuando ya tienes la suma, le adicionas a la izquierda, ceros. Bien sea utilizando la función [POWER](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/power-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), o [REPLICATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/replicate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

[Dar formato a números tipo factura](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/04/dar-formato-numeros-tipo-factura-00005/)

Comment: Era justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Para dar un par de alternativas más, te dejo una opción que es bastante rápida porque por alguna razón SQL Server realiza operaciones aritméticas de forma más rápida que operaciones de texto. La primera es haciendolo de forma directa, la segunda es básicamente para no tener que contar ceros. Dejo el ejemplo con un código que genera una secuencia de 10,000 números, pero es solo para tener ejemplos de como quedaría.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(id) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
select id, 
       RIGHT( id + 10000000001, 10), 
       RIGHT( id + POWER(CAST( 10 AS bigint),10) + 1, 10)
from cteTally;
```